# read_csv returns NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file 'Orders.csv' and I am able to see what it contains using "cat Orders.csv".

```
1,BSC,LIMIT_BUY,21460.883625169,0.00000445,0.00023821,0.09528632,1/17/2018 9:08:36 PM,1/17/2018 9:08:36 PM
```

But when I import it, it returns

```
O  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2     ...      Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8
0 NaN         NaN         NaN     ...             NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('Orders.csv')
print(data.head())
```

Comment: How working `data=pd.read_csv('Orders.csv', header=None)` ?

Comment: I am getting this output when using header=None`0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0    O NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4    8 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN`

Comment: What is separator?

Comment: Separator is ','

Comment: @HARSHITAGUPTA it would be nice if you can post a similar sample dataframe where users can see a small dummy data exacty how you can see in the csv file. ..?? it will be easier to replicate

Comment: 1,BTC-SC,LIMIT_BUY,21460.88365169,0.00000445,0.00023821,0.09528632,1/17/2018 9:08:36 PM,1/17/2018 9:08:36 PM
2,BTC-NEO,LIMIT_BUY,7.07155288,0.01321000,0.00023353,0.09341521,1/17/2018 9:42:34 PM,1/17/2018 9:50:11 PM